# Can I have an alias for multiple paths in Vite?

Tags: vite

I can config `vite.config.ts` to use an alias as follow:

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {

    return {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'list': 'src/Components/List/Index'
            },
            preserveSymlinks: true
        },
        plugins: [react()],
    }
})
```

However, I want to know whether it's possible to have **ONE** alias referring to tow or more directoreis? For example I have these directories:

```
src
   Components
       List
           Row.ts
           Index.ts
   Base
       Api.ts
       Index.ts
```

And I want to be able to import them this way:

```
import { Row, Api } from 'list'
```

Is it possible?